# android data binding encoding issue

Tags: java, android, mvvm, encoding, android-databinding

I am trying MVVM architecture in android for the first time.I am trying to use data binding. But I am facing an issue here.

Whenever I am compiling it during building its giving me **-1 error or sometimes `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception.**
 I've added all gradle stuffs that needed for data binding. I previously had similar problem with another activity layout file then one of my senior android pull it and run it solved the error and that actvity now running smoothly. I asked him what was the issue ...told me encoding issue of first line of xml layout.**Space problem**. Then i tried many ways in my windows machine the problem persisted with another layout file. Then i saw somewhere someone telling this data binding ***encoding issue*** only occurs in windows machine. The same project running on mac or ubuntu ..runs smoothly without any error.

*Note: My colleague then confirmed he has ubuntu OS. From then on I am thinking isn't there anyway to solve this encoding issue which occurs in windows machine??*

**Alas!! My post here in stackoverflow in hope that someone somewhere might have solution for this**.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.